# hausman test, random effect or fixed effect?which must be accepted

Tags: estimation, stata, panel-data, hausman

What is the limit for Hausman test?

```
 hausman onefe one

                 ---- Coefficients ----
             |      (b)          (B)            (b-B)     sqrt(diag(V_b-V_B))
             |     onefe         one         Difference          S.E.
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
FDIsharein~P |   -.0061599     .0113644       -.0175243               .
  TradeofGDP |   -.0026483     .0023264       -.0049748               .
       liter |    .0001273    -.0025736        .0027009               .
     laglife |   -4.424448     5.585048        -10.0095        1.810234
   lagmortal |    3.693138     1.375929        2.317209        .4881797
      lagpop |   -7.018966     -.212882       -6.806084        3.597954
   lagpercap |   -.0096546    -.0085061       -.0011486               .
Corruption~x |    .0276846     1.140028       -1.112344               .
Unemployme~l |    .0138161     .1309029       -.1170867        .0175023
Healthexpe~f |    .3305049     .5088894       -.1783846               .
Urbanpopul~l |    .3873496     .0862762        .3010734        .1565548
Militaryex~P |   -.0498372    -.0845921         .034755               .
     PHYSINT |    .0910831     .7238854       -.6328024               .
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                           b = consistent under Ho and Ha; obtained from xtreg
            B = inconsistent under Ha, efficient under Ho; obtained from xtreg

    Test:  Ho:  difference in coefficients not systematic

                 chi2(13) = (b-B)'[(V_b-V_B)^(-1)](b-B)
                          =       34.85
                Prob>chi2 =      0.0009
                (V_b-V_B is not positive definite)
```

That is my hausman test, should I accept random effect or fixed effect?

Comment: If you look for "Hausman test" via the search function there are many previous questions that discuss this test in their own context but give the reasoning for the interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

In a panel model, the individual effect terms can be modeled as either random or fixed effects. If the individual effects are correlated with the other regressors in the model, the fixed effect model is consistent and the random effects model is inconsistent. On the other hand, if the individual effects are not correlated with the other regressors in the model, both random and fixed effects are consistent and random effects is efficient.

Since the fixed effects model is efficient in both situations, the random and fixed effects estimates ought to be close when both are consistent and distant when random effects is not efficient. Roughly speaking, the hausman test is based on this distance. Therefore, if the distance is large, the null that individual effects are uncorrelated with the other regressors (aka random effects preferred) is rejected. Conversely, if the distance is small, the null is not rejected, and random effects is preferred because it is more efficient.

Since you have a large test statistic, the distance is large, and you should reject the null and use fixed effects.

However, there is an additional complication. In theory, the matrix V_b - V_B should be positive definite. However, the way the test statistic is constructed, this is not always true in practice. I know there is advice out there for what to do in this situation - you should be cautious about rejecting in these circumstances and look for more information.

Comment: you probably mean "Since the fixed effects estimator is **consistent** in both situations, the random and fixed effects estimators ought to be close when both are consistent and distant when random effects estimator is not **consistent**. Roughly speaking, the hausman test is based on this distance."...